# Selecting ordinary columns and columns formatted as XML in the same query

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

If I run `select columnA from tableA` I get the values from `columnA` from my table.

If I run `select columnB, columnC from tableA as xml path, root` I get the data from the 2 columns formatted as XML.

How do I go about combining the effects of the above 2 queries into one so that I get back `columnA` as-is and `columnB` with `columnC` as XML in a separate column labeled `myXml`?

I'm running this on a SQL2008R2 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with myTable as (
    select a.columnA,
    (select b.columnA, b.columnB 
        from tableA b
        where b.columnA = a.columnA
        for xml path, root
    ) as myXml
    from tableA a
)
select * from myTable
```

I was getting so caught up in the XML, that I failed to see that I needed a self-join on the table with 2 aliases!

Comment: Hello @DFlat. Please mark you post as an answer.